401 unauthorized Django Rest API Login
I'm having problems with my login API endpoint; it was working the last time I checked, now after working blindly for a few hours it doesn't work anymore and I don´t know what I've done. :)
Register is working smoothly, the user also gets created in the database and is visible in the admin panel.
The same credentials are not working for the login.
I´ve posted the code below:
views.py
#register new users
@api_view(['POST'])
def register_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = UserSerializer(data= request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data,status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.data,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

#userlogin with authentication tokens
@api_view(['POST'])
def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.data.get('email')
        password = request.data.get('password')
        user = None
        if not user:
            user = authenticate(email = email, password=password)
        
        if user:
            #token creation for the logged in user
            token, _ = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
            return Response(user.getDetails(), status=status.HTTP_200_OK) # type: ignore
        return Response({'error': 'Invalid credentials'}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)


models.py
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
   # username = models.CharField(max_length = 25 ,default = 'No name',unique = True)
    username = None
    email  = models.EmailField(default ="no email",unique = True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 25 ,default = 'No name')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 25, default = 'No surname')
    password = models.CharField(max_length = 25,default = "no password")
    
    
    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    
    def getDetails(self):
        return {
            'email': self.email,
            'first_name': self.first_name,
            'last_name': self.last_name
        }

serializers.py
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['id','email','password','first_name','last_name']
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

views.py
class UserLoginAPIView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    """
    An endpoint to authenticate existing users using their email and password.
    """

    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data
        serializer = UserSerializer(user)
        if serializer.is_valid:
            token = user.RefreshToken.for_user(user)
            data = serializer.data
            data["token"] = {"refresh": str(token), "access": str(token.access_token)}
            return Response.response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

Trying to log in user with the same credentials that were used for the register process.

You are facing with Django Rest framework, so it's better to you that follow the official documentation and use TokenObtainPairSerializer but that's ok. To create an Authentication from scratch in DRF :
please create a serializer for Login process like this :
class LoginSerializer(serializer.Serializer):
    password = serializers.CharField()
    email = serializers.EmailField()

ofcourse you'll need a CustomUserSerialzier like this :
class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializer class to serialize CustomUser model.
    """

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("email", "first_name", "last_name", "id",)

and in your views.py change the Login process like this :
from rest_framework_simplejwt import tokens

class UserLoginAPIView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    """
    An endpoint to authenticate existing users using their email and password.
    """

    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = LoginUserSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data
        serializer = CustomUserSerializer(user)
        token = tokens.RefreshToken.for_user(user)
        data = serializer.data
        data["tokens"] = {"refresh": str(token), "access": str(token.access_token)}
        return response.Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

I hope that help.
Note1 :
My Model and serializer are like :
models.py
class AllUser(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, phone, email, password=None, **kwargs):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('کاربر باید پست الکترونیکی داشته باشد')
        
        if not phone:
            raise ValueError('کاربر باید شماره تلفن داشته باشد')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            phone=phone,
            **kwargs,
        )
        user.is_active = False
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_staff(self, phone, email, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            email=email,
            phone=phone,
            password=password,
        )
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_active  = False
        user.is_superuser = False        
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, phone, email, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            email=email,
            phone=phone,
            password=password,
        )
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_active  = True
        user.is_superuser = True        
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    phone        = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    email        = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    password     = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    is_locked    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff     = models.BooleanField(default=False)    
    is_admin     = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    last_login   = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    created_at   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    USERNAME_FIELD = "phone"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["email"]
    
    objects = AllUser()

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.phone
    
    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

serializers.py
class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializer class to serialize CustomUser model.
    """

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("id", "phone", "email")


class UserRegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User 
        fields = ['phone', 'email', 'password']


class LoginUserSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    phone    = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField()
    
    def validate(self, data):
        user = authenticate(**data)
        if user and user.is_active:
            return user
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Incorrect Credentials")

and my view as what I typed in the above.
check this.

Currently the following error:
token = token.RefreshToken.for_user(user)
^^^^^
UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'token' where it is not associated with a value

This error means that user in views.py in "UserLoginAPIView" doesn't have value, because the "CustomUserSerializer" have issue with your "CustomUser" model. You need to change your serializer as your model.

Error: {email:'user with this email already exists'.} 400 Bad Request, I´ve added the LoginView in my question above

It trys to create another user with your serializer, you need to pass some fields in your "User" into "REQUIRED_FIELDS", to stop doing that by your serializer.

token = user.RefreshToken.for_user(user) still doesnt has the value, i think its from that line, would you be so kind and check what i´ve provided above, or are you certain that this the problem?

bro, copy my User model and also I provide you my Manager and test that out.

I insiste that you need to work with Phone instead of working with Email address, because after you implement this authentication, you have to work with OTP, so you need phone. That's why I'm using Phone in "USERNAME_FIELD".
